# Word for the colored edges of book pages, opposite the spine

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

What is a word for the colored edges of book pages, opposite the spine. Is there a term for this?

I'm not looking for *gilded* or *gold leaf*, as those are both specific to golden edges, nor am I seeking a term used for especially ornamental usages. The question came to mind after looking at a math textbook that used blue color to highlight a supplemental chapter, so the usage was mostly functional.

Anyway, in case my description is lacking, here's a cool picture (a book's cover actually) showing some antique books that demonstrate rather elaborate edge designs.

[image: edges of books - steven galbraith]

Comment: Please add a sample sentence. Are you looking for the word which describes the edge marker like your maths book, or one which a seller might use to describe the books in your image?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Both, either. If there is more than one word used to distinguish, it would be useful to know. "I turned to the _____ section - the one with the highlighted edges." "This lovely book has dyed edges, an example of ____"

Comment: @AndrewLeach A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: @Kris Yes, but different forms have different terms.

Comment: @AndrewLeach There are hypernyms at various levels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The coloured edge-pages are called, unsurprisingly, *edge painting* or *fore-edge painting*: that's actually already come up on a Stack Exchange site: [Why do some books have colors on the edges of the pages?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3488/why-do-some-books-have-colors-on-the-edges-of-the-pages)

Print Ninja corroborate that, and even call the speckled effect you see on some books [*fore-edge splatter*](https://www.printninja.com/printing-resource-center/printing-options/book-services/specialty-paper-options/custom-edges/painted). There are even people who do [remarkably detailed work](https://www.foredgefrost.co.uk/).

An edge mark which defines a particular section is called an [edge index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_index). This is produced slightly differently (by printing on the face of the page, at the edge, rather than *on* the closed edge) but has a similar effect.

Comment: Not painting. WP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fore-edge_painting & Miami Univ.: http://spec.lib.miamioh.edu/home/abc-for-book-collectors-fore-edge-painting/

Comment: "... nor am I seeking a term used for especially ornamental usages."

Answer (score -2):

[book edge coloring](https://www.google.com/search?q=book%20edge%20coloring&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU06He1bncAhVOWX0KHSRiB4oQ_AUICigB&biw=1024&bih=579)

A broader term not limiting to coloring: **[edge decoration](http://blog.paperblanks.com/2012/03/book-edge-decoration/)**.

Hope that helps.